# ThermodynamicData missing

Tags: curated-data, missing

Yesterday I was using `ThermodynamicData[]` and all was fine, today I try to use it and I get:

```
Missing[NotAvailable]
```

Does anyone know the fix? Thank you!

Comment: For what query?  It won't be able to answer all questions one might throw at it.

Comment: It's for anything. For example `ThermodynamicData["Water", "Entropy"]` gives back `ThermodynamicData::notent: Water is not a known entity, class, or tag for ThermodynamicData. Use ThermodynamicData[] for a list of entities. >>` and so on. I must have deleted something (I was cleaning my PC yesterday)? How can I get that feature back without reinstalling completely?

Comment: It works for me, so it's not the server (at least, not the one my laptop is contacting). What do the other *Data functions do?

Comment: ChemicalData["Caffeine"] work fine (it's the first time I ran it and it took some time to "Contact Wolfram Research site"). ThermodynamicData still doesn't work :(

Comment: A clear case of site entropy if ever I saw one..